# How to ask questions related to two different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, support, cross-posting, site-crossover

For example, I have a question about a game in Android, which is a suitable candidate for both *[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)* (more answers) and *[Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour)* (specific and experts answers). So how can I ask it? Should I ask on both the site or ask at one place and post the link on the second question on the second site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just said yourself that Stack Overflow provides more answers, but Game Development may have more specific answers from people with more expertise. Which would you prefer? I'm sure you're not looking for unspecific or answers from less experienced developers.

In any case, **do not post on *both* sites**. Choose *one* site, and post your question there. That's it. **Do not even post a question on the other site *just to link to the former*.** It creates duplication, noise, and hassle for people on both sites.

Comment: That's why I asked here first to not to create a duplicate question. The problem is I just assumed that there might be an advantage on asking question on stackoverflow due to more answer, but sometimes the answers are not good enough, so what to do in that case.

Comment: But what to do if want to understand different views and perspectives from different sites? We can get different views of people which might help to somebody with same problem.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - ask a **new** question tailored to the site you're posting on.